# running dag having airflow run: error: the following arguments are required: task_id, execution_date

Tags: airflow

Given I have an `easteregg.py` file:

```
from airflow import DAG

from dateutil import parser
from datetime import timedelta, datetime, time
from airflow.operators import PythonOperator
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from easteregg import easteregg_workflows as wf

defaults = {
    'owner': "JohnDoe",
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email': ['john.doe@mail.com'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=15),
    'start_date': parser.parse('2019-01-01 00:00:00')
}

dag = DAG('easteregg', default_args=defaults, 
    schedule_interval="*/5 * * * *")


step1 = PythonOperator(
    task_id="step1",
    python_callable=wf.run1,
    default_args=defaults,
    provide_context=True,
    pool="pool",
    dag=dag)

step0 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="step0",
    dag=dag)

step0 >> step1
```

and the `easteregg_workflows.py` file is simply:

```
def run1(**kwargs):
    logging.info("Hello airflow 1")
```

I now want to simply trigger this job on airflow. So I issued the command:

`airflow run easteregg`

but it's throwing me an error `airflow run: error: the following arguments are required: task_id, execution_date`.

What is the missing thing I need so that this DAG can run?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your dag file doesn't have anything missing. 
`airflow run easteregg` is an incorrect command. `airflow run` doesnt run an dag. instead it runs a `task_id`

Try `airflow run -h` for usage.

```
usage: airflow run [-h] [-sd SUBDIR] [-m] [-f] [--pool POOL]
                   [--cfg_path CFG_PATH] [-l] [-A] [-i] [-I] [--ship_dag]
                   [-p PICKLE] [-int]
                   dag_id task_id execution_date
```

Airflow requires the dag_id, task_id and execution_date

> positional arguments:
>   dag_id                The id of the dag
>   task_id               The id of the task
>    execution_date        The execution date of the DAG

Instead to run a dag you can use the `trigger_dag` command. https://airflow.apache.org/cli.html

`airflow trigger_dag easteregg`

```
Usage:airflow trigger_dag [-h] [-sd SUBDIR] [-r RUN_ID] [-c CONF] [-e EXEC_DATE]
                    dag_id
```